# como hago para que la variable "valor" vaya cambiado su valor

Tags: python

consigna:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero es buscar en orden si estas todas las letras de mi palabra "uade" distribuidas en la cadena. me gustaría saber una manera de ir cambiando el valor de la variable "valor"según vaya encontrando las letras.

```
 def orden(cadena,f=0,valor="u",u="u",a="a",d="d",e="e"):
        lista=[]
        if len(cadena)>=0:
            if cadena[f] == valor:
                lista.append(str(valor))
                if len(lista)%4 == 1:
                    return orden(cadena[f+1:],valor=a)
                elif len(lista)%4 ==2:
                    return orden(cadena[f+1:],valor=d)
                elif len(lista)%4==3:
                    return orden(cadena[f+1:],valor=e)
                else:
                    return orden(cadena[f+1:],valor=u)
            else:
                return orden(cadena[f+1:],)
                    
                
               
    cadena="tugarden" #buscar si se puede formar la palabra "uade"
    l=orden(cadena)
    print(l)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con "consigna"?

Comment: ¿A qué se refiere con que no necesariamente deben estar de forma consecutiva? ¿Podrías adjuntar los ejemplos?

Comment: ahi adjunte los ejemplos.

Comment: con cosigna me refiero a la foto donde pide que se cree una función para resolver el problema planteado

Answer (score 2):

Voy a proponer algo más simplificado y mucho más entendible. En primer lugar lo que necesitas es un ciclo `for` (o `while`) para ir recorriendo o iterando en la cadena e ir comparando los valores, ósea las letras.

Para este caso he utilizado una expresiones generador (generator expresion). En primer lugar se tiene que especificar 2 parámetros, el primero será la cadena o texto y el segundo una cadena con las letras o sub string que se quiera buscar.

```py
def validar_orden(cadena, palabras):
    cadena = cadena.lower()
    resultado = "".join( i for i in cadena if i in palabras)

    return resultado.count(palabras)
```

El código no es difícil de entender. En la primera línea simplemente pasamos el texto a minúsculas para evitar *case insensitive* (diferenciar entre minúsculas y mayúsculas).

La siguiente línea de código es nuestra *generator expresion* que sería una comprensión de lista si se le agregan los corchetes `[i for i in cadena if i in palabras]`. Esto se lee muy fácil. Se itera sobre la variable `cadena` letra por letra (`... for i in cadena`) y si la letra se encuentra como clave de nuestra variable `palabra` (`if i in palabras`) entonces se agrega esa letra a una lista (si tuviera los corchetes, pero dejémoslo en este concepto para no alargar la explicación).

Luego tenemos que juntar todos esos elementos y eso lo hacemos con el método `.join()`, lo que nos devuelve un string con todos los elementos juntos. Finalmente retornamos la cantidad de veces que la variable `palabra` se repite en nuestro `resultado`.

**Probamos**

```py
print(validar_orden("tugarden que no se que es","uade"))
```

**Resultado**

```
1
```

El código se puede simplificar a una sola línea pero prefiero dejarlo así para que se entienda lo que pasa. También se puede hacer el código más robusto, pero todo esto ya te lo dejo a ti :D

Comment: Que buena idea el crear la cadena palabras, no se me había ocurrido pensarlo de esa forma, muchas gracias de nuevo Christian.